# SQLite database size: more rows vs. more columns

Tags: sqlite

### Initial situation

Suppose I have a simple table that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AppData (
    id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    elementId               VARCHAR(36),
    timestampMs             INTEGER,
    enterTypeA              SMALLINT,
    exitTypeA               SMALLINT,
    enterTypeB              SMALLINT,
    exitTypeB               SMALLINT
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX app_data_index ON AppData (timestampMs DESC, elementId);
```

The index is added, because a lot of queries are performed to select entities based on `timestampMs` and `elementId`.
I'm storing each minute exit and enter values of different `types` for different `elements`. E.g.:

```
elementId, timestampMs, enterTypeA, exitTypeA, enterTypeB, exitTypeB

1, 1559383200000, 4, 3, 1, 5  
2, 1559383200000, 8, 2, 3, 7  
1, 1559383260000, 2, 2, 4, 0  
2, 1559383260000, 1, 0, 9, 2
```

### Problem description

New `types` need to be added to database. More `types` may also be added in the future. So I tried two different approaches:

**Approach 1:**
Adding more columns for new `types`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AppData (
    id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    elementId               VARCHAR(36),
    timestampMs             INTEGER,
    enterTypeA              SMALLINT,
    exitTypeA               SMALLINT,
    enterTypeB              SMALLINT,
    exitTypeB               SMALLINT,
    enterTypeC              SMALLINT,
    exitTypeC               SMALLINT
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX app_data_index ON AppData (timestampMs DESC, elementId);
```

**Approach 2:**
A new row for each `type` (means larger index):

```sql
CREATE TABLE AppData (
    id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    elementId               VARCHAR(36),
    timestampMs             INTEGER,
    enterValue              SMALLINT,
    exitValue               SMALLINT,
    type                    SMALLINT
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX app_data_index ON AppData (timestampMs DESC, elementId, type);
```

Personally I prefer approach 2, because it reduces duplication.

I've tested both approaches and inserted test data for 10 days with 5 `elements` and 3 `types`. Results showed, that the database size of approach 1 is much smaller than size of approach 2 (which is from my point of view reasonably logical, since approach 2 has three times more rows):

**Approach 1:** 8.2 MB | 144'000 entries
**Approach 2:** 24.6 MB | 432'000 entries

### Question

As I see, the size of the index in both solutions is about 50% of database size, so it's clear database size of approach 2 will always be larger.

Do more rows instead of more columns in SQLite always make such a big difference on database size?

So far I haven't found a solution to reduce the size of approach 2 even further. Perhaps this isn't possible due to the index?

Comment: You might be able to drop the `id` column and make it a [WITHOUT ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table with your current unique index the new primary key. That'll cut the size by quite a bit (and speed up lookups of the non-pk columns given the pk columns)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didn't know the `WITHOUT ROWID` before. So I've tested it, without index and the new primary key. It reduces the database size of the second approach about 12 MB.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of which of the two versions would take up more space is not so important as what the proper database structure is for your needs.  The second version is preferable, for several reasons:

- If you need to restrict the table to only certain types, a simple `WHERE` clause will suffice.  In the first version, you basically always get back *every* type when querying
- Aggregation is possible in the second version.  You may easily aggregate all timestamps by type.  This is much harder to do in the first version.
- If you need to link any of the columns in the second version to other tables, it is fairly straightforward.  On the other hand, in the first version, you would need to potentially link each separate enter/exit column.

Regarding storage, storing the same amount of data in either scheme should be fairly similar, certainly within an order of magnitude and probably within a factor of 2.  The design issue seems to be the bigger problem.

Comment: I agree with you, looking on the scheme the second approach is preferable and as a developer I would also prefer the second approach. But I'm using SQLite in an embedded environment where only limited storage is available. So it's probably a compromise between better schema and database size.

Comment: I guess it depends on how little space you have (e.g. on your Android phone), and how important this is.

Comment: It's not a lot ;) It's crucial if the database is larger factor 3 or not.

Comment: Finally i went with second approach by removing the PK `id` column, using `WITHOUT ROWID`, removing index and setting PK on previous unique index columns as suggested by @Shawn.